# How to modify User-Agent in WebView?

Tags: macos, swift, webview

I can't find way to modify User-Agent string at WebView component. I need to display mobile version of site (place iPhone user-agent) on Mac in WebView. I've tried:

That:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(["UserAgent": "Custom-Agent"])
```

And that:

```
let userAgent = NSDictionary(object: "Mozilla/5.0 (iPhone; CPU iPhone OS 8_0 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/537.51.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/8.0 Mobile/11A465 Safari/9537.53", forKey: "UserAgent")
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults(userAgent as! [String : AnyObject])
```

Nothing has worked. I've tried to place it in AppDelegate and right before WebView loadRequest method, no luck.

Comment: Have you tried to set customUserAgent property? If you have an instance of WebView you should be able to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to **xhruso00**. I've tried a lot of methods, but answer is so simple! :)

Use WebView's method:

```
//  The receiver’s custom user-agent string.
//  The custom user-agent string is used for all URLs.
//  If nil, then the receiver constructs a user-agent 
//   string that produces the best rendering results for each URL.

web.customUserAgent = "Here is custom user-agent"
```